# Flink UI for local application setup

Tags: user-interface, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have been trying to configure Flink UI for Flink application running locally in IDE. So I've set up relevant dependencies and execution environment. But Flink UI still does not work. What might be the reason of it?

By http://localhost:8081 there is a message

```
{"errors":["Not found."]}
```

Execution environment setup:

```
val conf = new Configuration()
conf.setBoolean(ConfigConstants.LOCAL_START_WEBSERVER, true);
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironmentWithWebUI(conf)
```

Dependency setup in build.sbt:

```
"org.apache.flink" %% "flink-runtime-web" % "1.9.1"
```

Comment: That looks like it should work. BTW, the second line (conf.setBoolean ...) isn't needed, but shouldn't hurt. Make sure you don't have something else listening on port 8081, and make sure the IDE has picked up the change to build.sbt -- maybe try rebuilding the project.

Comment: I usually get this error message, when I forgot to include the `flink-runtime-web` dependency. Could you double check that the correct library is picked?

Comment: @ArvidHeise Rebuilding the project helped. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks @arvid. this did it for me. change gradle from testImplementation to implementation in build.gradle made it work.